# classic ASP one page security

Tags: html, authentication, asp-classic

I have a page that needs to be more secure. Basically the page shows a few phone numbers and is written in html.  The server only supports asp.  and only 2-3 people will ever go to this page.  I would like the simplest user name password script, just for this page.

Is that possible?  Most of the tutorials I have seen are for a two page set up.

not database driven, password/username will be in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing this in a Windows domain environment on IIS you could just restrict the page based on the logged in user. No need for any forms. You have to make sure that the server is not set to allow anonymous login.

```
domainUsername = Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER")
if domainUsername = "domain\usera" or domainUsername = "domain\userb" then
    'show numbers
else
    'show error
end if
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've done any classic ASP, so the syntax might be a little off, but basically it will look like:

```
<% 
     Function Login(username,password)
        Login = False
        If Trim(LCase(username)) = "somebodywhocanseethepage" And Trim(LCase(password)) = "opensaysame" Then
               Login = True
        End If
     End Function

     Sub WriteLoginForm()
     %>
     <form action="<%= Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME") %>" method="post">
          <input type="hidden" name="_TRIGGER" id="_TRIGGER" value="LOGIN" />
          Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username"  /><br />
          Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password" /><br />
          <input type="submit" value="Login" />
     </form>
     <%
     End Sub

     Sub WritePageContent()
     %>
     <h1>Phone Numbers</h1>
     <ul>
       <li>867-5309</li>
       <li>911</li>
       <li>2 8 1, 3 3 oh, eight zero zero fo'</li>
     </ul>
     <%
     End Sub

     If Request.Form("_TRIGGER") = "LOGIN" 
         If Login(Request.Form("username"),Request.Form("password")) 
             WritePageContent
         Else 
             Response.Write "Login failed.<br />"
             WriteLoginForm
         End If
     Else
         WriteLoginForm
     End If
%>
```

I didn't test this, but if it's not 100% right, it's pretty close and you can tweak it to work how you need it to.  Let me know if you have to make any edits so I can update the answer for future users.

Answer (score 1):

Just check a password in the query string.  As per question requirements, this is extremely simple, and I really wouldn't dare put anything remotely sensitive in this script, but for absolute basic protection this should suffice.

I took the password off the query parameter name as I'm sure a lot of people sniff for that sort of data going through the web.

Example URL:

http://www.mysite.com/page.asp?mysecretquery=mypassword

```
<%
    if request.querystring("mysecretquery") = "mypassword" then
%>
<html>
<body>
    My data.
</body>
</html>
<%
    else
        response.write("Error")
    end if
%>
```